# Internally scaling training data during CV using GridSearchCV for hyperparameter optimisation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do SVM hyperparamater optimisation using GridSearchCV. Suppose I am feeding this function with training set data and labels (test split already isolated before function call).

```
def param_search(X, y):
    Cs = 10. ** np.arange(-3, 4)
    gammas = 10. ** np.arange(-3, 3)

    rbf_grid = {'clf__C':Cs, 'clf__gamma':gammas, 'clf__kernel':['rbf'],
        'clf__class_weight':['balanced']}
    lin_grid = {'clf__C':Cs, 'clf__kernel':['linear'], 
        'clf__class_weight':['balanced']}

    pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', svm.SVC())])

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=[rbf_grid, lin_grid],
        cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True), verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)
    grid_search.fit(X,y)
    return grid_search.best_params_
```

I want the GridSearchCV to evaluate each CV split with data scaled by the training calculated for that particular split. Is the StandardScaler() function currently being called 5 times for each set of parameters (which is what I want)? Or only once at the first call to GridSearchCV.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/normalization-prior-to-cross-validation This should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It did help answering a question I also wanted to ask. However, I still need to know whether the CV pipeline is performing as I suspect it is, even though the difference in final classifier generalisation may be negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it does fit the `Standard Scaler` 5 times for each set of parameters. Basically, the whole pipeline is fitted once per split and per choice of parameters, then evaluated.